# Почему не работает transition на элементе и псевдоэлементе?

Tags: html, css

Почему не работает `transition` на выпадающий элемент `extra-list` и псевдоэлемент `title::before` ?

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const trigger = event.target.closest('span');
    if (trigger) {
        trigger.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
});
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
addBtn.addEventListener('click',function () {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Третий список</span>' +
        '<ul class="extra-list">' +
        '<li class="extra-item">9 элемент списка</li>'  +
        '<li class="extra-item">10 элемент списка</li>' +
        '<li class="extra-item">11 элемент списка</li>' +
        '</ul>'
    list.appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 55px;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.title::before {
    content: '-';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
}
.title.hide::before {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    content: '+';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
}
.extra-list {
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.title.hide {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.title.hide + ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}
.extra-item {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.extra-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h2>Добавить список</h2>
            <button id="btn-add">Добавить список</button>
            <ul id="list" class="list">
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Первый список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">1 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">2 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">3 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">4 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Второй список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">5 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">6 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">7 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">8 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А что именно вы хотите добиться установкой свойства `transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;` ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 плавность выпадения элемента `extra-list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что свойство `transition` задает скорость и вид анимаций, только для четко определенного [списка свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). А то, что вы якобы хотите с анимировать в данном списке нету. `overflow: hidden; content: '-'; content: '+';` - это всё мимо.